# duplicateMovieClip in Action Script 3

Tags: actionscript-3, duplicates

My question is how to do this:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/zi63y771h38a2vo/Example.fla

In Action Script 3.0.

This is working timeline source code, with ready indexing values + sorting news via array.
Simple as that, how to create same thing in ActionScript 3.0?

I was searching on the websites/forums and I couldn't find any answer that was satisfying me, so I decided to create an account in here and ask for help.

If someone could remake this example on ActionScript 3.0, this could help us all, because I saw a lot of questions about duplicateMovieClip() function, but there were no strict answer  + example on it, so maybe let's create this?

This is my suggestion, code is in file or here:

```
    stop();

    var IDMovieClip = 0;
    var IDarray = 0;
    var Duplicate:MovieClip;
    MC._visible = false;
    var ARRAY:Array = new Array();

    ENTER.onRelease = function() {
        Duplicate = MC.duplicateMovieClip(IDMovieClip, _root.getNextHighestDepth());

        var ref = eval(Duplicate);
        ref.ID = IDMovieClip;
        ref.sortedID = IDarray;

        _root[ref.ID].windowID.text = "ID: " + ref.ID;

        Duplicate.Close.onRollOver = function() {
            trace(_root[ref.ID]._target);
        };

        Duplicate.Close.onRelease = function() {
            _root.ARRAY.splice(_root[ref.ID].sortedID,1);
            removeMovieClip(_root[ref.ID]);
            IDarray -= 1;
            _root.doSort();
        };

        ARRAY.push([IDarray, IDMovieClip]);
        doSort();

        IDMovieClip += 1;
        IDarray += 1;
    };

    doSort = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < ARRAY.length; i++) {
            _root[ARRAY[i][1]]._y = 10 + ((_root[ARRAY[i][1]]._height + 10) * i);
            _root[ARRAY[i][1]].sortID.text = i;
            _root[ARRAY[i][1]].sortedID = i;
            trace(ARRAY[i]);
        }
    };
```

[FLA PROJECT DESIGN IN JPG (MovieClips/Placement etc)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hdxxuosok5x7bip/Question.jpg)

(what You need to run it, if You dont want to download it from my DropBox)

If anyone could help, that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `duplicateMovieClip` in AS3, in ActionScript 3, you instantiate movie clips. I didn't find place for all used variables, I think it's part of some project, so you should adapt code for your needs. You also should read a bit about [Export for ActionScript](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/concept_export_for_as.html).

```
//Container for your objects            
var movieHolder: Sprite = new Sprite();
var id:uint = 0;
const padding: int = 10;

//Handler, that will add new objects to the scene
enter.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickEnter);

addChild(movieHolder);

movieHolder.x = movieHolder.y = padding;

function onClickClose(e:MouseEvent):void {
    movieHolder.removeChild(DisplayObject(e.currentTarget).parent);
    sortMovies();
}

function onClickEnter(e:MouseEvent):void {
    //Set up for MovieClip with form export for ActionScript
    var movie:MyFormMovie = new MyFormMovie();
    movie.windowID.text = "ID: " + id;
    movie.Close.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickClose, false, 0, true);
    movieHolder.addChild(movie);
    sortMovies();
    id++;
}

function sortMovies():void {
    var i: uint, len: uint = movieHolder.numChildren, movie: MyFormMovie;
    var posY: uint;

    for(i; i < len; ++i){
        movie = movieHolder.getChildAt(i) as MyFormMovie;
        movie.y = posY;
        movie.sortID.text = i.toString();
        posY += movie.height + padding;
    }
}
```